# Can I Create a Bigger Gmail Group from Several (Smaller) Gmail Groups?

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I have three gmail groups A, B and C,  each with say ten members.

Now I want create another bigger gmail group, say, BIG containing all the members of A, B, and C.

I tried simply clicking on the plus button and writing the names A, B and C. It did not work.

[image]

Please tell me whether it is possible to add a gmail group to another gmail group in some way, or I should not bother?

Do we have  only the exhaustive way of individually adding all those thirty plus names to BIG?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot add a Google Contacts group to another group directly.  Groups do not nest (kind of like how Gmail labels do not nest if you have not activated nesting in Labs).  However, we don't need to add users to BIG one-by-one either.  You have a couple options, actually.

**The Easy Way**

The most direct, and probably easiest for most circumstances, is to batch add users from A to BIG, then from B to BIG, then from C to BIG (etc.).  I assume you already have A, B, and C, so now create BIG.  Now go to A.  Click the "Select All" checkbox to select every contact in Group A.  Then, click the Groups menu (the drop-down menu with a three-person icon) and click the open checkbox next to the BIG group.  This will add everyone from A to BIG.

[image: Screenshot showing the three steps described above]

Removing contacts from lists can be done on a one-by-one or group-by-group basis (or any combination thereof).

**Something More Elaborate**

*UPDATE: Google no longer permits nested groups. No workaround at this time. My original notes still included here for reference purposes, and in the hopes that we find a workaround. Made my answer a wiki to facilitate other solutions!*

"Hang on!" you say.  (I don't know, what do you usually say?  It's a one-sided conversation right now, I get to put words in your mouth.  Here come some more:) "This easy way works for simple lists, but what if things get complicated?  What if Jane Test is leaving Group B.  Normally, this would mean that I remove her from BIG also.  But I have lots of contacts and groups; Maybe Jane should *still* be in BIG because she is a member of Group C also. Or, what if I forget about this issue and don't check Jane's contact card for other groups when editing it, and then take her out of BIG mistakenly?"

Now I think you're being picky, but there is a solution for this too. Instead of using Google Contacts for these more complex contact/group and group/group relationships, create some private Google Groups for A, B, C, and BIG.  Unlike Contacts groups, Groups groups (is that a thing?) can include other Groups groups.  (See: http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=167100)  Look, we're just going to call those "Groups" now.  You can email everyone in a Google Group by setting their member preferences (for that Group) to receive all posts by email, and then by emailing a post *to the group*.  Every member of the group gets the email.

That way, if Jane is in Groups B and C; and Groups A, B, and C are "members" of Group BIG; then when you remove Jane from Group B she will retain her membership in Group BIG in virtue of her membership in Group C.  So, you don't have to check and you are less likely to mistakenly remove Jane from BIG.

Comment: I would really like to use your second option there, but depsite the documented link you provide this does not seem to be supported in google groups. This is really important as for more complicated lists you need to single source everything to avoid a maintenance nightmare yet still structure it hierarchically.

I also tried hacking this so that a google group big@googlegroups.com has a member big2small@gmail.com. Then big2small@gmail.com forwards all email to small@googlegroups.com, However, google detected this nesting and explicitly prohibited it. Any other ideas?

Comment: Checked on this and you are correct, nesting groups no longer works. Dang it, Google! If I think of a workaround I will post an update.

Comment: Did you really mean to make this answer Community Wiki? It means you won't earn any reputation from any up-votes that it may receive.

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks for checking, but the change was intentional. I know that I will not have much time to research new solutions and the current solution is obsolete. There are real access management pitfalls to using the "Easy Way." So, while we've still answered the original question, our answer merely shifts the access management problem problem somewhere less obvious instead of truly solving it. I'd rather this page provide good answers to people in the future than to capture a few more up-votes on the current answer.

Comment: yeah, its a bummer because its almost perfect for my needs. Something like mailchimp seems overkill. Couple thoughts:

1) I think that the link you included applies to google apps, presumabley a more professional paid service google offers to businesses.

Comment: 2) I thought about working around this by doing a similar thing I tried above with a google group --> gmail account --> other google group. Google caught on to that. However, I was not sure if I created another address outside of google and tried the same think, like: google list --> yahoo group --> other google list. I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: @AndyCampbell 1) Both my original method and later testing were done in an Google Apps account, so this isn't a matter of differences between "free" and "premium/pro" Google. 2) If Google is actively killing this kind of grouping, they probably have a reason for doing so. My money is on an infinite looping issue of some kind. 2) Bouncing between providers would almost ensure that users in multiple groups receive multiple messages. You don't want that.

Comment: @AndyCampbell RE:Mailchimp (or something like it): There's a discussion, maybe an argument, that comes up almost every time someone online recommends MS Project to solve a project, task, or management problem. The argument goes like this: Bringing Project in to address task management is overkill. You don't need a sledgehammer to pound a nail. The problem with this line of thinking is that sometimes you have a large nail and no one makes a mid-sized hammer. I mean, obviously, try to make the small hammer work first! If it does not, though, suck it up and underutilize the really big hammer.